# How to save radio message log automatically with just log all printf()s and timeout activated on cooja

Tags: contiki, cooja

I'm wondering how to save the radio message log when I implement an automate simulation on cooja, the simulation will be repeated 10 000 times, and I'm interested on information given from IEEE 802.15.4 radio,
any ideas on how to do that ?

The info i want to save is in the pic attached.

[image]